# Decimal to binary python algorithm

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I'm trying to create an algorithm that converts decimals to binary. I can't use the built-in function in python to do so. This is what I've got.

```
n=int(input("enter a number"))

while n > 1:
    print(n%2)
    n //= 2
    if n % 2 ==0:
        print(n%2)
    else:
        print(n%2)
```

I'm completely fine with the 1's and 0's being printed in a separate line, as long as they're correct.

Comment: I tough this link give what you looking for
:https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134154/decimal-to-binary-algorithm

Comment: what if your number is negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
n=int(input("enter a number\n"))

while n >= 1:    # Should be >= 1, not > 1.
    print(n%2)
    n //= 2
    # Removed if else.
```

---

**Also, note that this will print binary in the reverse order.**

For the input `6`, the output will be:

```
0
1
1
```

Not:

```
1
1
0
```

If you want the later one, then you can store it in a list first and then print the list in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

This works quite well, returns a string, and it's a separate function, so you don't pollute your code:

```
def int2bin( num ) :
    result = []
    while num :
        result.append( str(num & 1) )
        num >>= 1
    return ''.join( result[::-1] )
```

The result:

```
>>> int2bin(4)
'100'
```

Comment: this answer helped me very much, BUT it doesn't work for 0. I had to add that edge condition to this method so it would return '0'.

Comment: @Alexandre you may replace `while num :` with `while num or len(result) == 0 :` to fix the case with `0`

Comment: @Alexandre the OP specifically asked for the algorithm that works with `num >= 1`, but you are correct, I should have make it work for `0` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do the [division and modulo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=divmod#divmod) in one step:

```
while n:
    n, d = divmod(n, 2)
    print(d)
```

This is basically the core of all answers. But it prints nothing for n = 0. And strange things happen for negative n. Let's handle all integers:

A complete program (without reversing the digits) may look like this:

```
if n == 0:
    print(0)
elif n < 0:
    print('-')
    n = -n
while n:
    n, d = divmod(n, 2)
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a track of what is going on, add some prints, and your binary result, where are you saving it? I propose a str, could be a list of int, I don't know, but this is one way (using your logic as a base):

```
n=int(input("enter a number"))

binary = ""
while n > 1:
    rest = n % 2
    n //= 2
    print("rest: {}".format(rest), "step: {}".format(n))
    binary = str(rest) + binary  
if(n>=1):
  binary ="1" + binary  

print(binary)
```

example:

```
enter a number: <b>2045</b>    
 1. rest: 1 step: 1022
 2. rest: 0 step: 511
 3. rest: 1 step: 255
 4. rest: 1 step: 127
 5. rest: 1 step: 63
 6. rest: 1 step: 31
 7. rest: 1 step: 15
 8. rest: 1 step: 7
 9. rest: 1 step: 3
 10. rest: 1 step: 1

 11111111101
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do like this:

```
n=int(input("Enter a number\n"))
res=""
while n >= 1:
  res=res+str(n%2)
  n //= 2
print(int(res[::-1]))
```

sample output 1:

```
Enter a number
10
1010
```

sample output 2:

```
Enter a number
99
1100011
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bin`, if you want a simple method and clean code, here is my code

```
n = int(input('Input any Integer: '))

dim = str(bin(n)).split('0b', 1)[1].strip()

print('\n'.join([n for n in dim]))
```

And then use `'\n'.join(...)` to print all number per each line

Answer (score 0):

You can use method bin()

```
def decimalToBinary(n): 
    return bin(n).replace("0b","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another compact solution with recursion:

Note: The output will be an one line string

```
def dec_to_bin(n):
    if not n:  # When n==0.
        return ''
    return dec_to_bin(n//2) + str(n%2)
```

Example:

```
print(dec_to_bin(19))
```

Output:

```
10011
```